# Does the unlocked CG from Hard mode open up any additional story elements?

Tags: utawarerumono

I read that if you complete the harder difficulties you get 2 of the last CG. I've seen both on the internet: one I think is Aruru, while the other is Eruru as a Shine Maiden.

I am wondering if these CG are just rewards or if they are connected to extra scenes that play out at the end.